# How to connect focus event from QLineEdit?

Tags: c++, qt

I have to connect focus event from some `QLineEdit` element (**`ui->lineEdit`**) to the method **`focus()`**. How can I do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no signal emitted when a QLineEdit gets the focus. So the notion of connecting a method to the focus event is not directly appropriate.

If you want to have a `focused` signal, you will have to derive the QLineEdit class. Here is a sample of how this can be achieved.

In the `myLineEdit.h` file you have:

```
class MyLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  MyLineEdit(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MyLineEdit();

signals:
  void focussed(bool hasFocus);

protected:
  virtual void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e);
  virtual void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *e);
};
```

In the `myLineEdit.cpp` file you have :

```
MyLineEdit::MyLineEdit(QWidget *parent)
 : QLineEdit(parent)
{}

MyLineEdit::~MyLineEdit()
{}

void MyLineEdit::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e)
{
  QLineEdit::focusInEvent(e);
  emit(focussed(true));
}

void MyLineEdit::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *e)
{
  QLineEdit::focusOutEvent(e);
  emit(focussed(false));
}
```

You can now connect the `MyLineEdit::focussed()` signal to your `focus()` method (slot).

Comment: Using this example straight without any change could/will generate the error "constructors not allowed a return type". The solution is to add a ";" after the class definition in MyLineEdit.h

Comment: Also if you got a "no such signal" is because you should not include the qualified name in void focussed(bool hasFocus), it must be void focussed(bool);

Comment: It's still not work i add the ; and focussed(bool), but there is still the message No such signal MyLineEdit::focussed()

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean connect as in signals/slots, focus event isn't a signal it's a virtual method you have to override in order to change the behavior:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#focusInEvent