# How to use focusInEvent and focusOutEvent

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow, qevent

I am implementing an application in which i am having 3 `QToolButton` and when the focus is coming on any `QToolButton` it should `resize`.
One of my friend has given me answer but i am unable to figure it out as i am inheriting `QMainWindow` class as well in my mainWindow. He is telling to inherit `QToolButton` too. But multiple inheritance problem will occur. So how exactly to use `focusInEvent()`.

```
MyCode:
mywindow.h :

class mywindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    mywindow() ;

protected:
    void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event); 
    void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *event);
    void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event);

private:
    QWidget *widget;
    QStackedWidget *stack1;
    QToolBar *tool;
    QListWidget *list1;
    QListWidget *list2;
    QVBoxLayout *vertical;
    QToolButton *button1;
    QToolButton *button2;
    QToolButton *button3;

public slots:
    void fileNew();
    void file();
    bool eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event);

};
```

mywindow.cpp :

```
mywindow::mywindow() : QMainWindow()
{   
  //some code
}
```

My friend's code which i have to merge :

```
class mywindow : public QToolButton
{
    private:
         int originalWidth, originalHeight;
         int bigWidth, bigHeight;
};

void focusInEvent ( QFocusEvent * event ) { 
                   resize(bigWidth,bigHeight); 
                   QToolButton::focusInEvent(event); 
}

void focusOutEvent ( QFocusEvent * event ) { 
                   resize(originalWidth,originalHeight); 
                   QToolButton::focusOutEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should do something like this

```
class YourButton : public QToolButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

    protected:

    void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* e);
    void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent* e);
};
```

in .cpp file

```
void YourButton::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* e)
{
    if (e->reason() == Qt::MouseFocusReason)
    {
      // Resize the geometry -> resize(bigWidth,bigHeight); 
    }


    QToolButton::focusInEvent(e);
}
```

then use the yourButton class in your mainWindow.

also (another option) you can use http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter in  your mainWindow .

Comment: It is giving this error: ‘YourButtton’ has not been declared

Comment: you have to create a new class inheriting QToolButton(example i gave YourButton as YourButton.h and YourButton.cpp). then in .h file you override the protected : foucusInEvent() and in .cpp file you can implement resizing of  the YourButton . see this link answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804115/qlineedit-focus-event. then you have to use this YourButton in your  mywindow class.

Comment: i am serching for you to show how to create a custom widget but couldnt able to find a proper example. you can follow the analogclock, shapedClock in qt examples but not that much relevant. if any one in this forum can help him .. please do it ..

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-analogclock.html and http://books.google.co.in/books?id=tSCR_4LH2KsC&pg=PA101&lpg=PA101&dq=how+to+create+custom+widgets+%2B+qt&source=bl&ots=E703pV27Fc&sig=Y2ip2QNzjM7kaoDImMsCfIq1HNw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=p6LXUuCZAcH_rAexroCwDg&ved=0CGwQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20create%20custom%20widgets%20%2B%20qt&f=false can help you

Comment: I have written everything but it is not working. No error is coming

Comment: The idea it self is good, but the way size is updated is incorrect, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from @Wagmare will work only for buttons outside a layouts.
To make it work inside of layout it should look like this:

```
class YourButton : public QToolButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
    // proper constructor and other standard stuff 
    // ..

protected:
    void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* e) {
        QToolButton::focusInEvent(e);
        updateGeometry();
    }

    void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent* e) {
        QToolButton::focusOutEvent(e);
        updateGeometry();
    }


public:
    QSize sizeHint() const {
        QSize result = QToolButton::sizeHint();
        if (hasFocuc()) {
            result += QSize(20,20);
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

With proper size policy it will also work without a layout.

---

Another cool solution without subclassing is a style sheet:

```
QPushButton:focus {
    min-height: 40px
    min-width:  72px
}
```